# Function to get the name in database table from the comma separated string

Tags: functions, loop, database, csv, get-post

I already created admin column in WP using this code:

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'page_custom_cols', 10);
function page_custom_cols($pages_columns, $post_type) {
$pages_columns['user_group'] = 'User Group';
return $pages_columns;
}
```

Now I added the function to get the user group id, this field is already in wp_post table but in a comma separated text just like this: " 1,7,2 " and I was able to display it using this function:

```
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'display_page_custom_cols', 10, 2);
function display_page_custom_cols($col_name, $post_id) {
if ('user_group' == $col_name) {
    $pages = get_post($post_id);
    echo $pages->group_access;
}
}
```

And it was showing now: http://screencast.com/t/z1uJ3KinklN

My problem right now is I want to display the the User Group Name not the ID
It was in the table 'custom_user_group': http://screencast.com/t/StBmVBfD0

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but this should work:

```
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'display_page_custom_cols', 10, 2);
function display_page_custom_cols($col_name, $post_id) {
  global $wpdb;
  $user_group = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * From custom_user_group",OBJECT_K); 
  if ('user_group' == $col_name) {
    $pages = explode(',',get_post($post_id));
    $output = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page ) {
        $output[] = $user_group[$page]->GroupName;
    }
    echo implode(',',$output);
  }
}
```

Comment: it really WORKS! thanks a lot bro.
I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: glad that I helped, cheers

Comment: yes, it really helps, I'm just looking for code to have a filter option on the top for the Group Names like a select option that list the Group Name then when click the Filter button it will display pages having the selected Group Names.
And I think thats really hard :(